# How to fix "Unrecognized resource types" for resource that is not included in template.yaml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli, aws-certificate-manager

As the title states, I'm seeing `aws cloudformation deploy` returning the following error:

```
Error:
    Failed to create/update the stack:
        stack-name-here, An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the GetTemplateSummary operation: 
            Template format error: 
                Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate]
```

While I did add this resource in a previous deploy, I've since removed it and it cannot be found in the console currently. There's no reference to this resource in my yaml template at all. Everything I have searched online would imply that I misspelled this resource or its unavailable in my region, but I am operating in us-east-1 (so it's available) and I've searched my template for the resource type with my editor and no results come back.

At this point, I'm stumped. I need info on how to correct this without having to delete the whole stack.

Comment: Did you remove it via CloudFormation or *manually*?

Comment: Cloudformation. Never touched the console or ran any aws cli commands.

Comment: Can you please share the stack template? That's strange if you've deleted it via CloudFormation - has it actually deleted the certificate?

Comment: I can but there's a ton of info in it i need to scrub, so it'll be a moment.

Comment: No worries, full but scrubbed is wonderful :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary so sorry i forgot to update this. This turned out to be a known issue with the AWS api and I had to reach out to support for a work around. I'll post the cause and possible workarounds once i get some free time this evening.

Comment: Ahhhhh, an AWS API bug! Extremely useful to know - thanks for updating :)